# How to tell whitch exceptions a .NET call throws?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, try-catch

If one has the following code:

```
data.SaveChanges();
```

(data is an `ObjectContext`)

The [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792.aspx) has listed the `OptimisticConcurrencyException` as thrown. That's fine but I known that a `UpdateException` can also be thrown (and possibly others too). How can I know which exceptions a method can throw?

I do not want to catch `Exception` as I only want to catch exceptions which I know I can handle in some way.
This is generally speaking - not just for the example above. There must be some way of knowing which exception a 'built-in' .NET method is throwing.

Comment: Some good reading http://stackoverflow.com/a/264755/555547 ;]

Comment: The MSDN library lists the exceptions that you *might* want to catch.  Another exceptions can be thrown, you *don't* want to catch them because they'll invariably mean something really nasty happened that you can't recover from.  Like UpdateException, you can't recover from a corrupt database.

Comment: Hans: Thank you for the explanation on the MSDN doc - that clarified some things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a "native" method; it's an ordinary method that happens to be written by Microsoft rather than you.
Actual native methods cannot throw managed exceptions (although COM interop will convert things to managed exceptions)

Unlike Java, C# does not have exception specifications, so there is no inherent way of knowing what exceptions a method will throw.

Your only options are the documentation or a decompiler.

Comment: You're right, I didn't know what to call it. But I guess it's just an ordinary method. Built-in to the .NET framework.
I know that C# doesn't have checked exceptions as for instance Java - I just thought (hoped) that there where some way of knowing whitch exceptions to handle.

Comment: Well, the documentation is not reliable and I'm not going to decompile the whole .NET framework. 
Guess I just have to write bug-free code :)
Thanks for the answer, anyway.

Comment: @NicklasJepsen Why are you so concerned about trying to handle exceptions? Standard practice is not to handle them and let them float up the call stack.

Comment: I'm not trying to handle every single exception - I would just like to know which one can actually occur.
In the book MCPD Exam Ref 70-518 it's stated that best practice is not just to let the exception float up the stack, but to handle them as close to the code causing it.

Comment: @NicklasJepsen: You should handle _relevant_ exceptions (that you can do something about) close to the relevant code.  Those exceptions are usually obvious and documented.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case (sorry if it's obvious but there're guys who don't know it) you can hover your mouse over the class name / method call in your editor view in VS. It shows you all the exceptions that can be thrown by the method if defined in documentation.