# What exceptions may a generated service reference throw?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, service-reference

I have added a web service in Visual Studio 2010 using the "Add Service Reference...". This generates some code in a file called `Reference.cs`. Now, if I call one of the methods I wan't to know what exceptions the method may throw. Presumably it can throw network related exceptions such as `SocketException` or `IOException`?

Regular methods in .NET can be checked on msdn or inside the source code to reveal what exceptions may be thrown, like for example [File.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s.aspx). Here it's clear what exceptions I should catch and rethrow to show error messages at a later stage.

**For those generated methods, how can I know what exceptions they may throw?**

Comment: thanks for the link. I know how to differ between exceptions that should be catched and exceptions that should bubble though - Hence this question. However, the generated code does not have any ///<exceptions> tag or anything hinting about what exceptions might be thrown.

Comment: Check the following [Thread][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264747/finding-out-what-exceptions-a-method-might-throw-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, there are 'standard' exceptions in this case, and 'custom' exceptions (those defined as `FaultContact`s by the service developer and present in the service contract reference).

In the first case your concerns, I would suppose, are [`CommunicationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.communicationexception.aspx) and [`TimeoutException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timeoutexception.aspx); these are documented possible exceptions for `ICommunicationObject.BeginOpen` and other 'opening' methods of [`ICommunicationObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.icommunicationobject.aspx) (the [base of the model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729840.aspx)). [`CommunicationObjectFaultedException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.communicationobjectfaultedexception.aspx) is documented for 'closing' methods.  There is also [`QuotaExceededException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.quotaexceededexception.aspx) for methods that send messages, such as [`IRequestChannel.Request`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms195350.aspx). Among the [many more that might be](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789039.aspx), these should be discoverable.

Worth noting, from an MSDN article linked above, is this:

> All exceptions thrown by channels must be either a
>   `System.TimeoutException`, `System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException`,
>   or a type derived from CommunicationException. (Exceptions such as
>   ObjectDisposedException may also be thrown, but only to indicate that
>   the calling code has misused the channel. If a channel is used
>   correctly, it must only throw the given exceptions.)

Then there are 'Faults', which are exceptions raised on the service-side and (potentially, if enabled) are detailed to the caller, the caller can then handle that or throw the proper client-side exception:

> When generating a fault, the custom channel should not send the fault
>   directly, rather, it should throw an exception and let the layer above
>   decide whether to convert that exception to a fault and how to send
>   it.

The channel `State` offers an event of `Faulted` to which you can subscribe to to be informed when such a state it reached, and perhaps act. By default (without configuring supression (?)) the faults will be raised as managed exceptions; again, to reiterate:

> In WCF clients, SOAP faults that occur during communication that are
>   of interest to client applications are raised as managed exceptions.
>   While there are many exceptions that can occur during the execution of
>   any program, applications using the WCF client programming model can
>   expect to handle exceptions of the [...] two types as a result of
>   communication.

And [this refers again](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732013.aspx) to the `CommunicationException` and `TimeoutException` mentioned above.

Lastly, for now at least, is the unexpected:

> `FaultException` exceptions are thrown when a listener receives a fault
>   that is not expected or specified in the operation contract; usually
>   this occurs when the application is being debugged and the service has
>   the
>   `System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceDebugBehavior.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults`
>   property set to true.

Comment: great answer with references and all! Really liked the first quote. Perfectly answered my question - I should catch CommunicationException and let the rest bubble through since they indicate I (or the generated code) use the channel methods incorrectly.